# Jquery Click() function scroll & Open content slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, offset

please take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/21/)

HTML

```
<div class="content-slide-menu">
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="link1"> <a href="#null" data-page="page1">blah blah</a>

    </li>
    <li id="link2"> <a href="#null" data-page="page2">twit twoo</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content-slide">
<div id="page1" class="content">
     <h3>blah blah</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh eros, commodo     sit amet risus a, bibendum venenatis mi. In sed tempus ante. In ac molestie tortor. Proin convallis, diam facilisis volutpat blandit,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="content">
     <h3>twit twoo</h3>

    <p>Quisque quis suscipit augue. Quisque eu augue eu elit imperdiet posuere. Integer tempor metus consectetur interdum porta. Fusce condimentum, metus eu commodo dapibus, diam metus vestibulum lacus,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="content-slide-menu">
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="link3"> <a href="#null" data-page="page3">Sit Amet</a>

    </li>
    <li id="link4"> <a href="#null" data-page="page4">lorem ipsum</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content-slide">
<div id="page3" class="content">
     <h3>Sit Amet</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh eros, commodo sit amet risus a, bibendum venenatis mi. In sed tempus ante. In ac molestie tortor. Proin convallis, diam facilisis volutpat blandit,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page4" class="content">
     <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>

    <p>Quisque quis suscipit augue. Quisque eu augue eu elit imperdiet posuere. Integer tempor metus consectetur interdum porta. Fusce condimentum, metus eu commodo dapibus, diam metus vestibulum lacus,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="footer"> 
<a href="#null" title="Twit Twoo" id="twit-twoo">Twit Twoo</a>
<br>
<a href="#null" title="lorem ipsum" id="lorem-ipsum">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-slide-menu {
float:left;
width:220px;
padding:0 10px;
}
.content-slide-menu li {
list-style-type:none;
}
.content-slide-menu a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#2b2b2b;
font-size:135%;
}
.content-slide-menu a:hover {
color:#3ca3c5;
}
.content-slide {
float:left;
width:440px;
margin-top:65px;
}
.content-slide .content {
display:none;
}
.content-slide .content h3 {
font-size: 150%;
font-weight: bold;
}
.content-slide .content p {
margin:5px 0;
font-size:110%;
}
.dots {
font-size:350%;
font-weight:bold;
 }
.active {
color:#3ca3c5!important;
}


#footer {margin-top:800px;}
```

JAVA

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".menu a").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $slider = $this.closest('.content-slide-menu');
    $slider.next().children('.content').hide();
    $("#" + $this.data("page")).show();
    $slider.find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass('active');
});
$('.content-slide-menu li:first-child a').click()
});
```

I have the content slide working as I want thanks to @Arun P Johny
However I now want to be able to click through to these different slides from else where on my site.

I want links on other pages and in my footer which click through to the section of the page that has the content slider on and opens it to that particular slide.

I also want this click function to offset from the top by 105px (I have a sticky top nav)
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have experimented with on click functions and can get it to scroll to the section containing the content slide w/ an offset but not open specific slides :(

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function for showing a specific page in a specific slider, that you can call then from anywhere of the site:

```
function showPage(menu, page) {
    $slider = $(".content-slide-menu[data-menu='" + menu + "']").first();
    $slider.next().children('.content').hide();
    $("#page" + page).show();
    $slider.find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $("#link" + page).children().addClass('active');
}
function showAndScroll(menu, page) {
    showPage(menu, page);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $slider = $(".content-slide-menu[data-menu='" + menu + "']").first().offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu a").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $slider = $this.closest('.content-slide-menu');
        showPage($slider.data("menu"), $this.data("page"));
    });
    $(".content-slide-menu").each(function(index, that) {
        showPage($(that).data('menu'), $(that).find("a").first().data('page'));
    });
});
```

For the scrolling, I made use of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/2526054

I added the code to Fiddle so that you can try it. Hope it is what you were looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/24/

Comment: Its not working for me in the fiddle you attached. 

The scroll top function I'm fine with its more clicking on the links in the footer to scroll up and open the slide in question that I am after. 

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/27/)

Comment: When scrolled up the offset needs to be 105px due to my sticky header - specifically after functionality "click on footer link lorem ipsum" scrolls up and opens section "lorem ipsum"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the Fiddle. This one should be better: http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/29/

Comment: Got it working with multiple links thanks so much :) Dissecting code from here is teaching me more than university did!

many thanks again!

Comment: Ive come across an issue im wondering if you could help me solve.
How would I get the 
    href="javascript:showAndScroll(1, 8)"

To work linking from another page, I have tried href=page.html#anchor" then an onclick="javascript:showAndScroll(1, 8)".. but nothing seems to be working?
Any ideas.